# PHP How to redirect back to a selected user-profile after updating their information as Admin?

Tags: php, html

I have built a Central Management System on my website using HTML/PHP/SQL, where Admin can create/update/delete other users etc.

Once Admin has updated a different users profile-page, I want the Admin user to be redirected right back to the same profile that they have just edited. For instance, if my Admin edits the profile of a user who's userID is "16" and clicks on the submit button, the Admin user is currently redirected to a blank "http://website.com/editstaff.php?updaterow=16" page, when they should instead be redirected back to "http://website.com/editstaff.php?staffid=16".

I would like to know how I can fix this problem? I suspect it is to do with the "action" element of the form on editstaff.php, as it points to "editstaff.php?updaterow=$iddata". However, I can't think of another way to get other users ID's when logged in as Admin than what I've written. I've tried a few other options, such as action="server.php" inside the form instead, but all the modifications I've made so far have broken the code.

Apart from the redirect issue, the rest of the code works and there are no issues with actually inserting the user profile updates into the database.

Apologies if there is a simple answer to my question as I am still trying to learn PHP, and this issue has stumped me all day.

edit staff.php

```
<?php
include ("conn.php");
include ("server.php");
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
...

<?php

$displayid=$_GET["staffid"];           
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `staff` WHERE staffID ='$displayid'";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                $email = $row["staffEmail"];
                $staffid = $row["staffID"];
                $iddata = $row["staffID"];
                $displayid=$row["staffid"];

<b><i class='fas fa-paper-plane'></i> Existing email:</b> '$email' 

  <div class='row'>

   <div class='col-xs-6'>

      <form action='editstaff.php?updaterow=$iddata' method='POST' id='updateStaffEmail'>

         <input type='text' class='form-control' id='updateStaffEmailInput' name='myUpdateStaffEmail' size='40' maxlength='60' placeholder='$email' required/> 

         <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='updateStaffEmailSubmit' value='Update' id='updateBtn' disabled> 

      </form>

   </div>

  </div>
```

server.php

```
//ADMIN UPDATE STAFF EMAIL

if(isset($_POST["updateStaffEmailSubmit"]))     {

    $updateStaffEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["myUpdateStaffEmail"]);
    $updateid = $_GET["updaterow"];

    if(empty($updateStaffEmail))   {
    array_push($errors, "Please enter a new email!");
    header("location: editstaff.php?staffid=$updateid");

    } else {

    $updatequery = "UPDATE `staff` SET staffEmail='$updateStaffEmail' WHERE staffID = '$updateid'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $updatequery) or die (mysqli_error($conn));

        header("location: editstaff.php?staffid=$updateid");

    }         
}
```

Also using Bootstrap v4.4.1

Comment: you already use header what is this question for ?

Comment: @Dilek The header does't do anything, it still always redirects to 'editstaff.php?updaterow=$iddata' regardless.

Comment: From your code it seems, that the form is not submitting to server.php file.. right?

Comment: @Asif. It submits. The SQL insert query always reaches the database and updates are actioned to the correct user profile. It's just the redirect that is a problem.

Comment: Did you try to add full URL to header function and add `exit` below the header?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to keep the redirections, you should know that header() requires more information in order to redirect a page. see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
<?php
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>
```

I tend to avoid redirecting users because it tends to flash the screen and also adds up on the loading time of your page.

From my understanding of your code, the solution would be quite simple. You do not need to redirect to an alternate url. You simply need to change the source of `$updateid`. So :

editstaff.php

```
<?php
include ("conn.php");
include ("server.php");
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
...

<?php

$displayid=$_GET["staffid"];           
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `staff` WHERE staffID ='$displayid'";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                $email = $row["staffEmail"];
                $staffid = $row["staffID"];
                $iddata = $row["staffID"];
                $displayid=$row["staffid"];

<b><i class='fas fa-paper-plane'></i> Existing email:</b> '$email' 

  <div class='row'>

   <div class='col-xs-6'>

      <form action='editstaff.php?staffid=$iddata' method='POST' id='updateStaffEmail'> <!--- Here you change the action ---!>

         <input type='text' class='form-control' id='updateStaffEmailInput' name='myUpdateStaffEmail' size='40' maxlength='60' placeholder='$email' required/> 

         <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='updateStaffEmailSubmit' value='Update' id='updateBtn' disabled> 

      </form>

   </div>

  </div>
```

server.php:

```
//ADMIN UPDATE STAFF EMAIL

if(isset($_POST["updateStaffEmailSubmit"]))     {

    $updateStaffEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["myUpdateStaffEmail"]);
    $updateid = $_GET["staffid"]; # Here you change the source of the variable

    if(empty($updateStaffEmail))   {
    array_push($errors, "Please enter a new email!");

    } else {

    $updatequery = "UPDATE `staff` SET staffEmail='$updateStaffEmail' WHERE staffID = '$updateid'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $updatequery) or die (mysqli_error($conn));


    }         
}
```

Then again, I do not see any code that shows what you are displaying when either pages are displayed. But from that you should be able to set a new variable and then test if it is set using isset() or empty().

Hope this helps

Comment: @ L. Ouellet, thank you this worked! Great advice. I actually basically tried this earlier but I didn't remove the header from server.php and that broke the code.